# Why does adding a child anchor makes the overflow visible on its parent anchor?

Tags: html, css

I have a confusing problem that I've been struggling with since yesterday, so basically I'm building a windows 8-like website, where each box is a list item It's more complicated than the code I'm putting but the problem is narrowed down there..

```
 <ul>
      <li>
           <a href="#" class="box">
                <ul>
                <li>Logos</li>
                <li>Book covers</li>
                <li>Magazines</li>
                <li>Wedding invitations</li>
                </ul>
                <img src="image.jpg">
           </a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

css:

```
 .box {
 display: block;
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 }

 img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 }
```

So far it works perfectly as expected and the image is contained to .box with the overflow hidden. But once I add an anchor tag after the child ul list items....

```
 <ul>
      <li>
           <a href="#" class="box">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Logos</a></li>
                <li>Book covers</li>
                <li>Magazines</li>
                <li>Wedding invitations</li>
                </ul>
                <img src="graphic.jpg">
           </a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

The overflow becomes visible, the image visibility takes all the available space, it's no longer visible only in .box boundaries. Why is that happening? and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest an anchor within another one, that's likely the cause of your problem*. There are a few choices, depending on what you are trying to achieve:

Remove the `a.box` and just have your links within each list item, like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
```

Or add some JavaScript to open the relevant link only when the 'logos' list item is clicked. You can see an example of this using jQuery [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/f4LJC/). The relevant code is:

```
$('[data-href]').on('click', function() {
    window.open($(this).data('href'));
});
```

And then in the html:

```
<li data-href="http://www.google.com">Logos</li>
```

* it's invalid. Different browsers will likely behave differently, as they all try and 'fix' invalid markup with varying degrees of success. Here, your first anchor gets closed off too early and that causes the layout to fall apart.

Comment: yup, it does indeed fail in the W3C validator. Remember, the validator is your friend :)

Comment: I see, that explains it, thanks. and just to be clear "links within each list item" as in <li href="#"> is this what you mean? is it okay to do this?

Comment: <li href="#"> didn't work, as expected. I guess you meant having separate anchors for each item of the list?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Just as per the link on 'logos', I meant that each list item could *contain* a link.

Answer (score 2):

In Your code you have an `a` tag inside another `a` tag ... but you can't do this. [Nested Links are illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2) ... it's interpreted like your first `a` tag is closed by the next one.